# Firebase Push Key Undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to get the the key from a firebase push command when using cloud functions.

```
const params = {
    date: Date.now(),
    movie,
    movieId: movie.id,
    userId: user.uid,
    group: 'home',
    type: 'watched'
};

const pastRef = event.data.adminRef.root.child(`pastActivity/${user.uid}`);

var newPostRef = pastRef.push().set(params);

var postId = newPostRef.key;

console.log(postId); //undefined
```

The postId however comes back as undefined. Have try a few other suggested methods without any results.

Comment: `movie` in params does not have a value?

Comment: @PeterHaddad That is new ES6 syntax, where `{ movie }` is a shorthand for `{ movie: movie }`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ohh okay, thank you!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

`Reference.set()` returns a **void** promise that resolves when the write operation completes. You can't get the key of it. Instead, split the `push()` and `set(...)` into separate statements, so that you can capture the reference

```
var newPostRef = pastRef.push();
newPostRef.set(params);

var postId = newPostRef.key;

console.log(postId); //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version can be used if you don't need the `newPostRef` variable

```
//var newPostRef = pastRef.push().set(params);
//var postId = newPostRef.key;

const newPostRefKey = pastRef.push(params).key
//this pushes the data and returns the key
```